# Mysql insert and update impressions with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to record number of advertisement impressions and clicks per day in database.
I'm using PHP to insert and update that data in mysql.

The script that display specific advertisement and store data in db looks like:

```
...count the number of rows in db with this advertisement ID ...
if ($total == "0") {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO impressions VALUES ('".$id."','1','0',NOW('')");
}else{
mysql_query("UPDATE impressions SET impressions=impressions+1 WHERE id=$id;
}
```

Table in mysql database:

```
   id  |   impressions  | clicks  |   date
   ------------------------------------------
    5  |      104       |   23    | 2010-06-23
```

Can I somehow use limit for the number of impressions per day?

For example if advertiser wants to limit impressions of his add to 5000 per day.

How can I do that?

Comment: Stop showing the ad after 5000 impressions (duh!)

Comment: @Robus - 5000 impressions per day and continue day after till again reach 5000

Comment: Extra tip: Don't count before you insert/update, but issue an UPDATE and if mysql_affected_rows() returns 0, you run INSERT. And oh, use mysql_real_escape_string() for query parameter values!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a limit of impression per day, you need to have a place to save that configuration from the advertiser. After that, you only needs to select the adds that is that current impression is inferior than the limit for the current day!

Other thing... you should read something about sql injection and how to prevent that.

I hope my answer help you in any way.

Regards